# Python: Bokeh Timeseries visualization

Tags: python, time-series, bokeh

From documentation of `bokeh` the only example I have found until now for Timeseries is the following: [Stock Returns](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/correlation.html)

I couldn't find any example how to plot timeseries with different plot styles.

Is there a way to create a Timeseries figure using the `rect` function? More specifically to have the time values in x ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Plotting `rects` is very similar, but you have to add some additional arguments which specify the shape of the rectangles.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook

dates = np.arange('2015-01-01', '2015-01-31', dtype='datetime64[D]')
values = np.cumprod(np.random.lognormal(0.0, 0.04, size=dates.size))

td = (dates[1]-dates[0]).item()
width = int(td.total_seconds() * 1000) # width in microseconds?

r = figure(x_axis_type="datetime")
r.rect(dates, values, height=40, width=width, angle=0, 
       height_units="screen", width_units="data")

show(r)
```

The `x` and `y` specify the center of the `rect`, and the width and height 'move' away from that center. You can also consider `quads`, for the difference see:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#bars-and-rectangles

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Timeseries` high-level chart is a line chart. For other uses, you'll want to use the `bokeh.plotting` API, which is only slightly more verbose. In addition to `rects` and `quads, another option is to use`segment`and set the`line_width` to be large. This can be useful for, e.g. OHLC type charts.